# Regex: How do I match something that may OR may not be between [ ]

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

I am parsing a log using Perl and I am stumped with as to how I can parse something like this:

```
from=[ihatethisregex@hotmail.com]
from=ihatethisregex@hotmail.com
```

What I need is `ihatethisregex@hotmail.com` and I need to capture this in a named capture group called "email".

I tried the following:

```
(?<email>(?:\[[^\]]+\])|(?:\S+))
```

But this captures the square brackets when it parses the first line.  I don't want the square brackets.  Was wondering if I could do something like this:

```
(?:\[(?<email>[^\]]+)\])|(?<email>\S+)
```

and when I evaluate `$+{email}`, it will just take whichever one that was matched.  I also tried the following:

```
(?:\[?(?<email>(?:[^\]]+\])|(?:\S+)))
```

But this gave strange results when the email was wrapped in a pair of square brackets.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would it be a problem if the regex also worked on invalid input like `from=[ilovethisregex@hotmail.com`?

Comment: Well, it's impossible to have an unclosed square bracket.  They exist as a pair.  The two lines are the only cases.

Comment: I think woolstar’s solution is the way to go, but if you think you really should have this in one regex, you might want to consider `from\s*=\s*\[?(.*?)\]?$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/(\[)?your-regexp-here(?(1)\]|)/

 (  )                              capture group #1
  \[                                 opening bracket
     ?                                 optionally
      your-regexp-here             your regexp
                      (?( )   )    conditional match:
                         1           if capture group #1 evaluated,
                           \]          closing bracket
                             |       else nothing
```

Note that this does not work in all languages, since conditional match is not a part of a standard regular expression, but rather an extension. Works in Perl, though.

EDIT: misplaced question mark.

Comment: Sorry for late acceptance of answer.  This was what I used and it works great.  Yes, it ONLY works for Perl!

Answer (score 3):

I tend to do these kinds of things in two steps, just because its clearer:

```
my ($val)= /\w+=(.*)/ ;
$val =~ s/\[(.*)\]/$1/e ;
```

This trims off `[]` seperately.

Comment: I'm sorry, but maybe the title wasn't clear enough.  I'm trying to do a MATCH, not a stubstitution.

Comment: The first line does a match.  The second line does a substitution on the result to make it conform.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    /from\s*=\s*\[?(?<email>(?:[^\]]+))\]?/;
    print $+{email}, "\n";
}

__DATA__
from=[ihatethisregex@hotmail.com]
from=ihatethisregex@hotmail.com
```

Output:

```
ihatethisregex@hotmail.com
ihatethisregex@hotmail.com
```